# 2-torsion in $\pi_1$ of codimension 0 submanifolds of a 3-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Let $M$ be a compact 3-manifold.  I am interested in necessary/sufficient conditions for $M$ to have the following property: If $M = M_1 \cup_S M_2$ where $S$ is a connected surface and $M_1,M_2$ are connected compact 3-dimensional submanifolds, then $\pi_1(M_1)$ and $\pi_1(M_2)$ do not contain any 2-torsion.

I know that this is true when $M = S^3$ but I do not know how to prove this in other cases. I might guess that the above property is equivalent to $\pi_1(M)$ not containing any 2-torsion.  One sufficient condition is that $\pi_2(M_1) = \pi_2(M_2) = 0$ for any such decomposition - but I want a condition that does not look at all possible splittings.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't make sense to me, because that's not a condition on $M$, but on $M_1$ and $M_2$. I mean, if that's an OK condition, then "for any splitting, $\pi_1(M_1)$ and $\pi_1(M_2)$ have no 2-torsion" is also an OK condition, isn't it? And then your problem's solved. So I don't quite get what you're looking for here. I'd assumed it was some statement about $M$ that's *not* conditioned on a universal quantification over splittings.

Comment: @JohnHughes I was just pointing it out - but of course, as you say, it is really not at all a useful condition to me as you have to somehow check it on all splittings.

Comment: You say $M_1$ and $M_2$ are closed, so $S$ is not their common boundary, but some embedded surface? Is this surface required to be 2-sided?

Comment: @SteveD It has to be a typo, otherwise $M$ wouldn't be a manifold.

Comment: I think $M_1$ and $M_2$ are supposed to be 3-manifolds-with-boundary.  I'm *guessing* that the surface $S$ is supposed to be a compact surface (without boundary) embedded in $M$ with a nice tubular neighborhood, so that one can apply the van Kampen theorem, for instance, but OP would have to clear that up. I'm hoping that we're not looking at things like the Alexander horned sphere...

Comment: Sorry - fixed - just a typo with the adjectives